# cpp.sh can't find any

Tags: c++

I am compiling online with [C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh).

In one of my programs, I'm required to use `std::any`. I don't know any alternatives to `std::any`, so I have decided to use it.

C++ Shell can't seem to find `any.h` and `std::any`. What can I do?

Code:

```cpp
#include <any>

    // Class creation, functions etc...

    void CallIfFunction(std::any variable) {
        (void)variable;
    }
```

Comment: Don't change the question after you've accepted an answer. Post a new question if you need help with templates.

Comment: Ok. I will remember thanks! I was trying to improve my question that I deleted (I am following instructions on the meta about been banned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPP.sh does *not* support C++17 (the only options available are 98, 11, 14). Try to compile with this code:

```
#if __cplusplus == 201703L
    #warning this is C++17
#else
    #error this is NOT C++17
#endif
```

you'll get this error:

> 4:2: error: `#error this is NOT C++17`

The `std::any` is a C++17 feature and is only available if your compiler is C++17 compliant.

Comment: Okay. So is there anything besides `std::any`?